# Am I leaking this ObjectiveC Object?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-management, memory-leaks, autorelease

```
@interface foo: NSObject
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *aMutableArray;
@end

@implementation
@synthesize aMutableArray

-(void)somefunction {
    // Illustration
    self.aMutableArray = [[[NSMutableArray alloc]init]autorelease];
    self.aMutableArray = [[[NSMutableArray alloc]init]autorelease];
    self.aMutableArray = [[[NSMutableArray alloc]init]autorelease];
}
@end
```

I have done code similar code to this in other parts of my program, but I needed to be certain that this does not cause a memory leak. With my understanding of `autorelease`, this object is released correctly right?

**[EDIT - added question]**
One question though: the property above has a retain attribute, so when the compiler creates the setter function, the setter code will look something like this:

```
somecode..
retain newObj
release oldObj
somecode..
```

in the code above, I assigned 3 objects to aMutableArray.
Each time they are assigned, the setter function did a **retain** on the newObj and a **release** on the oldObj. So, since the setter method already did a release, will there be a problem when the autorelease kicks-in to release the object a second time?

Comment: Yes. However you got a typo: missing brackets [ at front of NSMutableArray

Comment: I have edited the question above to include subsequent question i have on your answer. thanks

Comment: Nope, it will not leak. You are autoreleasing them so even though the setter retains them, the autorelease pool will be flushed, and the release in the setter will also be invoked, so the retaincount of 2 will be 0 eventually. So again, nothing wrong with this code :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it will be released correctly if you also release it dealloc method:

```
- (void) dealloc{
   [aMutableArray release];
   [super dealloc];
}
```

Note also that you can shorten your code using equivalent convenience `+array` method of NSMutableArray:

```
self.aMutableArray = [NSMutableArray array];
```

Comment: Thanks for the convenience method tip. This was illustration though, the code is much more complex :)

Comment: I have edited the question above to include subsequent question i have on your answer. thanks.

Comment: ouch thanks, intended to put ellipsis there but forgot them for some reason

Comment: @theface to answer your second question, there is no overrelease, since your call to `autorelease` balances your call to `alloc`.  The `release` in `-dealloc` is necessary to balance the `retain` in the setter.

Comment: @DaveDeLong ok, i'm guessing that the compiler implementation of the the setter function is a lot more complex than simply retaining the newObj and releasing the oldObj then? If it were that simple, i think there might be an overrelease.  I'm more inclined to believe you because you got high rep and you're an Apple framework developer :)

Comment: @theface nope, it's not more complex than that. It might do a little more depending on how the method is define (`nonatomic` or not, for example), but at its heart it's retaining the new value and releasing the old one.

Comment: ok, i see what i was calculating wrong..
on:
**self.aMutableArray = [[[NSMutableArray alloc]init]autorelease]**

... the **alloc** increases retain count by 1, and the **setter** increases retain count by another 1 making retain count 2 at that point. I accidentally thought it was still 1. You're right, no over release present.