# Objective-C Object Allocation

Tags: objective-c, memory-management

Consider the following two allocations of arrays.

```
NSMutableArray* alpha = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];

NSMutableArray* beta = [NSMutableArray array];
```

Assuming nothing else retains `alpha` or `beta`, my understanding is that the result of both is the same. The retain count on both will 0 and therefor they will be cleared up once they leave scope.

I have a sneaking suspision that I am not fully grasping the subtle implications between the two. After reading a [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8553544/768510) answer I know the latter is a convenience method, but I would like to understand the differences.

What is the difference between the two lines of codes above in regards to memory management?

Comment: good question; and I wonder if there's a difference between those two lines before and after ARC...

Comment: I know this has been answered but I can't resist! `The retain count on both will 0` is very misleading - the retain count will be _at least_ 1 until the autorelease pool next releases it's objects. and you can't rely on retain count at all because you don't know what else inside the frameword is retaining your objects so it might be more than one (and it might have been added to the autorelease pool more than once!). And you don't know exactly when the autorelease pool will release it's objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those two lines are equivalent. In both cases objects are created that you have a reference to but not an owning reference. However, they'll be on the autorelease pool. That means they'll last as long as the pool does, which if you've not done anything special will be until control returns to the run loop. Objects like that therefore (usually) survive beyond their scope — that's useful because it means you can (and usually do) provide autoreleased objects as return results.

The rule is that methods that return an object but do not contain 'new', 'alloc', 'retain' or 'create' in their name will return an autoreleased object. That's the logic behind `+array` returning an autoreleased object.

As an aside: if you enable ARC then autoreleased objects will still be returned but the compiler may be smart enough to take them out of the autorelease pool (which is something you can't do manually) and release them manually in a calling method where it won't affect program flow.

Comment: Thank for verifying my assumption as well as clearing up a grey area for me relating to autorelease pools.

Answer (score 4):

No, you're correct. `+[NSMutableArray array]` probably looks something very much like this internally:

```
+ (id)array
{
    return [[[self alloc] init] autorelease];
}
```

"Factory methods" like `+[NSMutableArray array]` do just return an autoreleased instance for you. There's actually more to it than this in certain optimized Cocoa and Foundation classes, but for the purposes of memory management semantics, it really is this simple.

Comment: Just to nitpick: `[NSArray array]` will probably hand you back a singleton instance of an empty immutable array. You probably meant to say `[NSMutableArray array]`.

Comment: Thank you for verifying my assumption and giving me an insight into `+ (id)array`.

Comment: @Kevin Ballard, I did mean to say `[NSMutable array]`, but I was actually referring to the kind of situation you mention in my "more to it than this" caveat. Still, the singleton empty immutable array returned by `[NSArray array]` can and should be treated exactly like an autoreleased object. Thanks for catching the typo.

Comment: I guess I have to recognize that correctly typing `+[NSMutableArray array]` is just not my strong suit ;-). Anyway, I've updated my answer to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

There really isn't any difference in the two, besides the second one looks cleaner, and is less bytes.

As you mentioned `[NSMutableArray array]` is just a convenience method which will internally in fact return pretty much exactly what the first method is doing.

Comment: Thank for verifying my assumption.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference at all. It is simply a shortcut.

Comment: Thank for verifying my assumption.